# make echo includes quotes in generated file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile rule that generates a C file based on the content of a list.

```
LIST = foo \
       bar

generated.c:
    @echo "Creating $@"
    (echo "#include <stuff.h>";      \
    echo "void init_local() {";      \
    for i in $(LIST) ; do            \
       echo "    init_$$i();";       \
    done;
    echo "}") > $@
```

On a Linux platform, this gives me the result I expect:

```
#include <stuff.h>
void init_local() {
    init_foo();
    init_bar();
}
```

However, on my windows 7 64-bit platform with GNU Make 3.82 (x86_64-w64-mingw32),
I get the following (all on one line):

```
"#include <stuff.h>";   \"void init_local() {"  \ 
   for i in foo bar; do echo "  init_$i();"; done; echo "}"
```

I have also tried to break out the rules for individual lines:

```
    echo "#include <stuff.h>" > %@
    echo "void init_local() {" >> $@
    ...
```

With that solution, I have 1 string per line, but the quotes are still there!

How would I change the rule to get the generated file correct on both the Linux and Windows platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because DOS has own command separator - **&** (similar to **;** in bash). But I would suggest using make echo instead of shell echo that will work in DOS and in bash:

But this is not all, as I understand you don't need quotes (**""**) in output, that is why you  shouldn't pass them to echo, but instead escape special symbols with **^**.

```
ifeq ($(OS_TYPE),linux)
    Q="
    ESC=
else
    Q=
    ESC=^
endif

generated.c:
    @echo "Creating $@"
    echo $(Q)#include $(ESC)<stuff.h$(ESC)>$(Q) > $@ 
    echo $(Q)void init_local() {$(Q) >> $@
    ...
```

In addition, your bash **for..;do..;done;** loop should be replaced with make **$(foreach, $(LIST), echo ...)** to be correct for both shells.

Yes, I know, this is becoming look ugly, but that is because of weird DOS rules. If you need to generate a lot I would suggest using awk, python or perl.

Comment: I did try that, but the quotes are still echoed! Freaky!

Comment: Yeah, I was just writing about that, I have spent lot of time on my previous job to generate files in make - fighting with different crazy DOS escaping, but then I decided to use perl.

Comment: OK, nice, I am glad that this helped